# test class showing system.Assert exception ,provide solution

Tags: trigger, failing-tests

```
@IsTest
public class Incrementtrigger_update_Test 
{
    Public Static TestMethod Void Test1()
    {
        Test.StartTest();
        SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c app =new SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c(CTC_Offered__c = 12.00,Pre_CTC__c = 12.00,Prop_CTC__c=12.00);
        Insert app;
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, app.Id);

        Appraisal__c Apprase  =  new Appraisal__c (Appointments__c= App.Id , Status_of_Apprisal__c= 'Yes',Amount_Incremented__c=24,of_Increment__c=24 );
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Apprase.Id);
        SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c ap =new SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c(CTC_Offered__c = 12.00,Pre_CTC__c = 12.00,Prop_CTC__c=12.00);
        Insert ap;
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, ap.Id);

        Appraisal__c Appr  =  new Appraisal__c (Appointments__c= App.Id , Status_of_Apprisal__c = 'No',Amount_Incremented__c=24,of_Increment__c=24 );
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Appr.Id);

        Test.StopTest();
     }
}
```

Comment: insert Appr; before System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Appr.Id); and insert Apprase; before System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Apprase.Id);

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy You should post that as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Id for a new object is created once it is persisted to database. 
As in your code you are checking for not null Id before inserting the object, so the assert statements are failing.

You can try this to avoid the exception;

```
//line 12
insert Apprase; 
System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Apprase.Id);

//line 18
insert Appr;
System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Appr.Id);
```